# R Shiny Leaflet map doesn't center properly after expanding the container

Tags: css, r, shiny, leaflet, shinyjs

I have a Shiny app that correctly collapses the datatable beneath a leaflet map, extends the map and then also brings back the datatable with a button click. The problem is something happens to the orientation of the viewport during this process, so that when I click the map reset button afterwards, it zooms north of where it should. I'm sure it's probably something simple that I'm missing but I would greatly appreciate any help figuring this out.

You'll notice when you start the app, move around the map, then click the map reset button, the map centers correctly. However, after you click "Expand Table," then "Show Table," then click the map reset button, it zooms north of the center. I've also had to compensate the positioning of the coordinates in the else statement below in order to properly center. So something must be getting off track once the map viewport is expanded. I've thought about adding conditional coordinates for the setView of the initial rendering of the map based on whether toggleState is TRUE or FALSE but wanted to find a solution to the viewport issue.

EDIT: I also noticed if you change size of the browser window, the map centers automatically. I just need the map reset button to do that!

EDIT #2: Adding this line to the end of the second observeEvent simulates resizing the browser window and seems to do the trick!

```
shinyjs::runjs("window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));")
```

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML('
      /* Adjust the main panel style */
      .mainPanel {
        height: calc(140vh - 75px);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
      }

      /* Adjust the map height */
      #map {
        flex-grow: 1;
        height: 70vh !important; 
      }

      /* Adjust the reset button style */
      .reset-button {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1em;
        right: 1em;
      }
      
      .mainPanel {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      
      .output-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px; 
        transition: height 0.3s ease; 
      }
      
      .collapsed {
        height: 0 !important; /* Set height to 0 when collapsed */
        overflow: hidden; /* Hide content when collapsed */
      }
      
      .expanded {
        height: 200px !important; /* Calculate available height when expanded */
      }
    '))
  ),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(
      div(class = "mainPanel",
        leafletOutput("map"),
        div(
          class = "button-container",
          actionButton('toggleSizeButton', 'Expand Map')
        ),
        div(
          id = "outputContainer",
          style = "width: 100%; height: calc(100vh - 200px); overflow-y: auto;",
          DT::dataTableOutput("table")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)  

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  tableState <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(tableState(), {
    toggleLabel <- ifelse(tableState(), "Show Table", "Expand Map")
    updateActionButton(session, "toggleSizeButton", label = toggleLabel)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$toggleSizeButton, {
    tableState(!tableState()) 
    shinyjs::toggleClass(selector = "#outputContainer", class = "collapsed")
    
    toggleState <- input$toggleSizeButton %% 2 == 0
    
    if (!toggleState) {
      shinyjs::show("outputContainer")
      leafletProxy("map") %>%
        setView(lat = 36.1627, lng = -86.7816, zoom = 12)
      
    } else {
      leafletProxy("map") %>%
        setView(lat = 36, lng = -86.7816, zoom = 11) # have to adjust the coordinates here for proper centering
    }
    # added this part to simulate browser resizing - seems to fix it for now!
    shinyjs::runjs("window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));")
  })
    
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      
      leaflet() %>% 
        addProviderTiles("CartoDB.DarkMatter") %>%
        setView(lat = 36.1627, lng = -86.7816, zoom = 11) %>%  
        addResetMapButton() # works on startup but zooms north after datatable is brought back into view
    })
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      mtcars
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I can't see the problem. Could you shorten your question and focus on the actual question, i.e. delete all edits concerning the second solved problem and shortly describe the remaining problem?

Comment: Remove or comment out this line:

shinyjs::runjs("window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));")

Run the rest of the code then click "Expand Table," then "Show Table," then click the map reset button and map zooms north of the center. That was the original problem.

Comment: But this line fixes the problem and everything is solved, right?

Comment: It seems to fix the issue, yes, but at the time of the original post I wasn't aware of this solution. It sort of feels like it's a workaround for a bug in shiny/leaflet though. Why doesn't leaflet just center correctly without the need for a window resize event?